# Auto-covariance and Cross Covariance Function in Matlab without using imbuilt functions

Tags: matlab, covariance

`x` and `y` are 1x100000 vectors.

[image: Questions]

I have calculated the mean and variance of `x` and `y`. When I want to calculate the autocovariance and cross covariance function the simulation lasts maybe 5 minutes because of my loops. It is not allowed to use `xcorr`, `xcov`, `mean`, `cov`, `var` etc.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

```
%%Mean of Vector x

Nx=length(x);
mx= sum(x)/Nx;

%%Mean of Vector y

Ny=length(y);
my=sum(y)/Ny;

%%Variance of x

varx=0;

for i=1:Nx
   varx=varx+(abs(x(i)-mx)^(2));
end
varx=varx/Nx;

%%Variance of y

vary=0;
for j=1:Ny 
   vary=vary+(abs(y(j)-my)^(2));
end
vary=vary/Ny;


%%Auto-Covariance function of x

for k=1:Nx  

Cxx(k)=0;

for i=1:(Nx-k+1)    
   Cxx(k)=Cxx(k)+(x(i+k-1)-mx)*conj((x(i)-my));  
end
end

%%Auto-Covariance function of y

for s=1:Ny  

Cyy(s)=0;

for j=1:(Ny-s+1)    
   Cyy(s)=Cyy(s)+(y(j+s-1)-my)*conj((y(j)-mx));  
end
end
```

Comment: Is using `conv` or `fft` allowed? :-)

Comment: If `fft` is allowed, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the fact that `FFT(corr(x, y)) = FFT(x) * conj(FFTy))`:

```
corrxy = ifft(fft(x) .* conj(fft(y)));
corrxy = [corrxy(end - length(x) + 2:end); corrxy(1:length(x))];
```

To get the cross-covariance just multiply the correlation by the standard deviations:

```
covarxy = corrxy * sqrt(varx) * sqrt(vary);
```

To get the autocovariance, compute the cross covariance between `x` and itself.

Comment: Is this for autocovariance function?

Comment: Generally speaking this is for _cross-covariance_, but if you substitute `y = x` (that is, if you compute the cross-covariance between `x` and itself), you will get the _auto-covariance_. You can compare the result to `xcorr(x, y)` and see.

Comment: corrxy = [corrxy(end - length(x) + 2:end); corrxy(1:length(x))];
Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a re-write of this code:

```
%%Auto-Covariance function of x
for k=1:Nx  
    Cxx(k)=0;
    for i=1:(Nx-k+1)    
       Cxx(k)=Cxx(k)+(x(i+k-1)-mx)*conj((x(i)-my));  
    end
end
```

The following code takes out the inner for-loop:

```
% x is a [Nx x 1] vector (lets say Nx = 50)
Cxx = zeros(Nx,1); % [Nx x 1] vector of zeros
for k = 1:Nx,
  a = (x(k:Nx)    -mx); % If k=3, then x(3:50) and a is [Nx-k+1 x 1]
  b = (x(1:Nx-k+1)-my); % If k=3, then x(1:48) and b is [Nx-k+1 x 1]
  Cxx(k) = a'*conj(b);  % Cxx(k) is always 1x1. (*) is a matrix multiply
end
```

Since `x` is a really large vector, and the way to take out the the last for-loop `for k=1:Nx` is to make a [Nx x Nx] matrix, I'm going to leave it at the above answer for now. Plus, if you have the `parfor` function in the [Parallel Computing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/) then you can parallelize it to make it run even faster.

Comment: When I run your code I take an error like this:




Error in ==> part3 at 46
  Cxx(k) = a'*conj(b);  % Cxx(k) is always 1x1. (*) is a matrix multiply
 
??? Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Comment: I think that has to do with the size of the variables we're creating. http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1107.html
I can't be sure, but perhaps your system can't handle having x, Cxx, a, and b (all of which are on the order of [100,000 x 1])? In any case, sorry it didn't work out.